# Audible alarm when On Latex compilation error

Tags: emacs, compilation-error

Hei. — I'm trying to make Emacs give an audible signal in case of a LaTeX compilation error.

Normally, Emacs is in "silent" mode, and wants that to continue after an audible  LaTeX-alarm.

Thanks you in advance

Kjetil

Comment: I think you should post this question in the emacs' stackexchange https://emacs.stackexchange.com/. Anyway, what function or shortcut do you use to compile? Do you use auctex?